# Нажать на GroupBox pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Я использую pywinauto для автоматизации telegram, я хочу нажать на эту кнопку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я сделал `app.Telegram.print_control_identifiers()` и нашёл её [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но у неё нет имени или уникального id. Как я могу нажать на него?

Comment: Телегу лучше через Telegram API автоматизировать. У них Python client для этого есть. Десктопное приложение у них раньше вообще accessibility не предоставляло. Может сейчас что и поменялось, но всё равно через Web API легче должно быть 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Так-то можно до него достучаться, но нужно поэкспериментировать с подбором `found_index` (например, 11, но это неточно, нужна визуальная проверка):

```
app.Telegram.child_window(control_type="Group", found_index=0).click_input()
```

Можно попробовать метод `.invoke()`, если он реализован на стороне приложения (не факт).